# Going from $S(E,V)$ to $S(T,V)$

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, entropy, volume

Starting from the differential of $S(E,V)$, we know that $$dS = \frac{dE}{T} + \frac{p}{T} dV.$$ Now I want a function of entropy of other variables e.g. $S(T,V)$ where the differential is supposed to look like $$dS = \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_V dT + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T dV$$ because I am not comfortable with the fact to just assume that I can change variables like that without some procedure. I have read some answers in posts that say that u should get the function $S(T,V)$ by inverting the relationship $$\left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial S} \right)_V = T$$ but I haven't really figured how exactly that relation helps me find the entropy with the variables I want. Would be really thankful if someone could clear that up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function $S(E,V)$ and you know that $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_V = \frac{1}{T}$ (that is equivalent to $\left(\frac{\partial E}{\partial S}\right)_V = T$), now you can invert this relation (you assume that is invertible) and obtain $E(T,V)$ finally you substitute this in the entropy and get $S(E(T,V),T) \equiv S(T,V)$.

Comment: going from $\left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial S} \right)_V = T$ to $E(T,V)$, so you integrate both sides wrt $S$ and assume that $T$ is a function of the variables $S$ and $V$ or how exactly do you invert the relation? Sorry if it's a stupid thing to ask.

Comment: No, you invert $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}\right)_V=\frac{1}{T} $, in this expression the variables are: $E$, $T$ and $V$

Comment: As I see it the left side in general is a function of $E,T$ and $V$, as u said in ur answer, so u can say that $\frac1{T} = f(E,T,V)$. So from here on you just assume that you can solve for $E$ and from the equation above end up with $E(T,V) = ...$?

Comment: Yes, you have $f(E,V)=\frac{1}{T}$ (were $f$ is the partial derivative of $S$ with respect to $E$ so depends on $E$ and $V$)

Comment: Okay thank you I think I got it now. Will mark it as answered.

Comment: Ok, let me make another comment, you will soon see that we generally you don't use $S(E,V)$, but $E(S,V)$ and that to change variable you will use the Legendre transformation. So I advise you, before proceeding, to study this mathematical tool a little, so that everything will be clearer to you later. Good luck.